# Load JSON by email in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, filter

Is there a way to load only JSON objects from my JSON file that have the same email address? I am able to load all the data, but I want to be able to load only by an email address. I have a query selector, but past that I'm not sure how I would search by email and then render it in my `loadedSurvey.js`.

loadedSurvey.js:

```
class LoadedSurvey extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="col-6 mx-auto text-center">
            <h1>Load Your Survey</h1>
            <div>
              <Filter
                onTextChange={(text) => this.setState({ filterString: text })}
              />
            </div>
            {SubmittedData.map((submittedData, index) => {
              return (
                <div className="text-left">
                  <div>
                    <p>
                      <strong>Name: </strong>
                    </p>
                    <p>{submittedData.fullName}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p>
                      <strong>Email: </strong>
                    </p>
                    <p>{submittedData.email}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p>
                      <strong>
                        Are you aware you are canceling with your current
                        company and entering a contract with Company, Inc.?{" "}
                      </strong>
                    </p>
                    <p>{submittedData.message}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p>
                      <strong>
                        Do you understand you will be paying a monthly rate of
                        $49.95?
                      </strong>
                    </p>
                    <p>{submittedData.radioChoice}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p>
                      <strong>Check all that apply. I understand:</strong>
                    </p>
                    <p>{submittedData.checkboxChoice}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p>
                      <strong>Which of the following is not true?</strong>
                    </p>
                    <p>{submittedData.Select}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p>
                      <strong>Select all that apply:</strong>
                    </p>
                    <p>{submittedData.multiSelect}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
            <form>
              <LoadSurveyComponent />
            </form>
            <Link
              name="loadedSurveyToHomeButton"
              className="btn btn-primary my-5 mx-5"
              to="/"
            >
              Home
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default LoadedSurvey;
```

and `FilterComponent.js`:

```
import React from "react";

class Filter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          onKeyUp={(event) => this.props.onTextChange(event.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Filter;
```

Sample data:

```
  {
    "fullName": "Louis",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "message": "No",
    "radioChoice": "No",
    "checkboxChoice": [
      "I will be responsible for $49.95 each month until my contract is over.",
      "I am entering into a new contract.",
      "I have three days to cancel.",
      "If I cancel after three days, I will be responsible for the remainder of the contract.",
      "My system is monitored and if it is set off, the cops will come to my home."
    ],
    "Select": "I will be responsible for the remaining balance of the contract if I cancel early.",
    "multiSelect": [
      "I am happy with the system as it has been explained to me.",
      "I am happy with the level of customer service I have received today.",
      "I am happy with the representatives who have helped protect my home today."
    ]
  }
```

Comment: No. You'll get the whole file every time. You can of course filter it once you parse it though.

Comment: @KevinB thanks, I'll look into parsing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't filter it out during the load, however, once you have the array of objects you can filter it. In your case you should be able to do it right before the .map.

```
{SubmittedData.filter(submittedData => {
  return submittedData.email === 'email@email.com';
}).map((submittedData, index) => {
```

Comment: You can also filter it when you put it on your state which would be more efficient than having the filter run every time a render does. but unless performance became a problem, I wouldn't worry about it too much.